# Which datatypes do I have to use to write this function in Cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I found this nice piece of code and I want to rewrite it in Cython to learn Cython. Further I want to plot a speed comparison gain between python for loop, numpy and cython. This is how my comparison looks in the moment for around 40k rows:

[image: 40k_rows]

```
def sliding_window_slicing(a, no_items, item_type=0):
    """This method perfoms sliding window slicing of numpy arrays

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : numpy
        An array to be slided in subarrays
    no_items : int
        Number of sliced arrays or elements in sliced arrays
    item_type: int
        Indicates if no_items is number of sliced arrays (item_type=0) or
        number of elements in sliced array (item_type=1), by default 0

    Return
    ------
    numpy
        Sliced numpy array
    """
    if item_type == 0:
        no_slices = no_items
        no_elements = len(a) + 1 - no_slices
        if no_elements <=0:
            raise ValueError('Sliding slicing not possible, no_items is larger than ' + str(len(a)))
    else:
        no_elements = no_items                
        no_slices = len(a) - no_elements + 1
        if no_slices <=0:
            raise ValueError('Sliding slicing not possible, no_items is larger than ' + str(len(a)))

    subarray_shape = a.shape[1:]
    shape_cfg = (no_slices, no_elements) + subarray_shape
    strides_cfg = (a.strides[0],) + a.strides
    as_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided #shorthand
    return as_strided(a, shape=shape_cfg, strides=strides_cfg)
```

I tried this, but I can't make up my mind about the datypes i have to use:

```
%%cython -a 
#cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, cdivision=True, nonecheck=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython


cpdef np.ndarray cython_sliding_window_slicing(long[:,:] a, long no_items, int item_type=0):

    cdef:
        long no_slices, no_elements
        long subarray_shape
        (long,long) shape_cfg 
        np.ndarray strides_cfg

    if item_type == 0:
        no_slices = no_items
        no_elements = len(a) + 1 - no_slices

    else:
        no_elements = no_items                
        no_slices = len(a) - no_elements + 1

    subarray_shape = a.shape[1]
    shape_cfg = (no_slices, no_elements) + (subarray_shape,0)
    strides_cfg = (a.strides[0],) + a.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape_cfg, strides=strides_cfg)
```

In the moment I receive the error: `Expected a tuple of size 2, got tuple`
The array I use on the function is like this: `example_array = np.random.randint(1000,size=(40, 8))`

I hope somebody could  help and explain to me what I need to change and how I can debug the script (with jupyter notebook?).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This doesn't look like  a good `cython` candidate, neither for learning or speed.  I don't see any irreducable loops that can be sped up by converting to `c`.  Apart from some simple shape and strides calculations,it just calls `as_strided`.  I doubt if `cython` is going to try to "compile" that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That's what I was wondering as well. nevertheless I am interested to rewrite it in cython. To understand which datatypes to use here and what I have to adjust would be a learning for me. And I really can't imagine how the graph looks when I run this in cython. That"s what I want to know in the end :)

Comment: Asstrided returns a `view`, so is relatively insensitive to the array size. All you are measuring is a setup time.

Comment: @hpaulj Hahahaha. Okay. Accepted answer. Now I can imagine the graph correlation. Thank you!